# Are parentheses in jQuery or CSS selectors allowed?

Tags: jquery, css

On my page there are 2 parent DIVs: #div1 and #div2. Both can contain children DIVs.
I need to select using jQuery all these children DIVs from both parents together.

```
<div id="div1">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Is it allowed to write `$("(#div1, #div2) > div")` ?

I know, I can write `$("#div1 > div, #div2 > div")`, what is the same. But if the expression "> div" would be something much more complex, and I would have more parents, the expression would get unreadable.

Comment: Why don't you just add a class to the divs you want to select

Comment: Why not then: `$("#div1, #div2").children('div')` ???

Comment: In CSS it's possible with any() (:matches() in CSS Level 4 spec): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any . But with JS it's wiser to go with classNames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the expression is not valid.

You could do `$("#div1, #div2").find('> div')` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Break it up into pieces

```
$("#div1, #div2").find("> div")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the parent div's a class:

```
<div class="pdiv" id="div1">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="pdiv" id="div2">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

and then use the selector over the class:

```
$(".pdiv > div")
```

This would be a cleaner solution if you have more than just a handful of parent `div`'s.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `add` and `children` functions:

```
$('#div1').add('#div2').children('div')
```